# Python Walrus Operator in While Loops

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.8, control-flow, walrus-operator

I'm trying to understand the walrus assignment operator.

Classic while loop breaks when condition is reassigned to False within the loop.

```
x = True
while x:
    print('hello')
    x = False
```

Why doesn't this work using the walrus operator?
It ignores the reassignment of x producing an infinite loop.

```
while x := True:
    print('hello')
    x = False
```

Comment: `x := True` is evaluated at the top of the loop, every time the top of the loop is reached. So the value of `x` tested is always `True`. `x = False` was not ignored. `x := True` changes the binding of `x` to `True` _regardless_ of what `x` was bound to.

Comment: Got it! too bad. I really wanted that to work! hehe.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that that assignment happens once before the loop is entered, but that isn't the case. The reassignment happens before the condition is checked, and that happens *on every iteration*.

`x := True` will always be true, regardless of any other code, which means the condition will always evaluate to true.

Comment: I'm legitimately curious: what is bringing people to this question? Is there a common misconception that `:=` will only execute once when used in a condition, or is it for unrelated issues? If it's the latter, I almost feel like the question could be "repurposed" to be a better use of the traffic.

Comment: The first time I ever visited this question, it was the former. Now, it is the latter. @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume we have a code:

```
>>> a = 'suhail'
>>> while len(a) < 10:
...   print(f"too small {len(a)} elements expected at least 10")
...   a += '1'
```

The assignment expression helps avoid calling `len` twice:

```
>>> a = 'suhail'
>>> while (n := len(a)) < 10:
...   print(f"too small {n} elements expected at least 10")
...   a += '1'
... 
too small 6 elements expected at least 10
too small 7 elements expected at least 10
too small 8 elements expected at least 10
too small 9 elements expected at least 10
```